# Prevent GhostScript to turn PNGs into JPEGs

Tags: pdf, compression, ghostscript

I use GhostScript to fix/repair non-compliant/corrupted PDFs in order to let them be successfully opened by PDF readers and be edited with Acrobat Pro without errors or warnings.

```bash
gs \
  -o repaired.pdf \
  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
  -dPDFSETTINGS=/default \
   corrupted.pdf
```

I noticed however that PNGs images into the PDF are turned into JPEGs with a loss of quality.

Is there a way or specific option to avoid that?

I searched into the **[documentation](https://ghostscript.com/docs/9.54.0/Use.htm)** without success.

Comment: I wonder if qpdf can achieve what you want.

Comment: Recent versions of Ghostscript (you don't say what version you are using) don't decompress DCT or JPEG2000 image streams, they are preserved untouched. Unless, obviously, you choose to do something like change the colour space of the image, or its resolution. Note that PDF files cannot contain PNG images, so I don't know why you think that Ghostscript is making JPEG out of PNG.